# Edge coloring of complete bipartite graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm reading [this paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272566/1-s2.0-S0095895600X01694/1-s2.0-0095895691900077/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMH%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDKO33gczZEraRU2eBBFtdshK3mOGBJ5CRZquRffDjrZwIgM9wBf7eOybxucqDt2s%2BxyYVaSQoon3skV6mUF%2B47fhgq2wQI2v%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDIlWlJEXSDs9BFZ8ayqvBHmBpAwkzPwOtErCijR%2B9MKN%2BfXh8nk5IzHzB9GAIAHyd2T%2F1aqlXV9hPwPgDq%2BSRvgKHFaUUNNXbVNVZhjbTqBpChKCXtZItLPqG78ecaQtCy7pPNpoY6Q3e7DLsxDRwXmLQYwszsRopoMdDjqWYdEDknCG0sizkOe5v2BdU8tOTNVy2jbsX7ecQpCO%2BpUBMB%2FTVCwcPEcrPYP6R7ckl0XO2p8e11oo6SNTI1OVmAbCvbHybGYF2chXeEDKff1%2FBspMAsdDQAd%2B4oDxluuVm9hWbCovB1J1KqoDOYVQ7uIFeK%2B1dICqFLMuOH%2BOzY5LwR6hVwGL0JSP094c%2BfgBgYun2orh%2F3u4HJWBOEqgmwV77mZlSbq0LvySzFGdYfiYMy5ks3ZslmclTMlhq8gH7iHmmdazsx9GSV63oh12NMIQl8r3t%2BfoomuYZaUilO%2BSjKbxl0M6natL3udGy0RnenML9opoLqRh036vuAXE6DdXYelRU7kv6i2t7PES%2FHYBbE600QZ%2Fa43rWHBcE7Ihj2QqV7AHFNm23E4j3MASD%2BN5LfmeidYBpK%2BObFC%2FkisKpUecxE72n2jqHhaeUDjLb8MTOSZzazHYL8z7JtI2z6Tb2EYcKXo0yVollW6EmPAXx3J1AB%2FM6wkIbZ4S7LE%2ByD3L6nuUmQIP53H8TU2UJuoykQnhs4pyWuFFRGT0xDsGjw7Matgxy2Uy19me0uJEP%2FbevkjcsektILPWcTfDL9EwysHnlQY6qQG5hRhVVArPoLUKTBIgy2VxLv75yX%2FK4aCR1DyVT3ZgFxAZyaXsrCxk0O9MicP98SzANd%2BJFbf63oEZMDIwtyYlu4fJMEG9vCDzBygpTS5zdyzBDkYDWS7htdZx7NWtygPaNoygIJf3eMpm07PJalnN73WWfbfOxn2P3hzGXOmivZ7JFrRg%2FE7H5ZhEqPZGPzVz%2FAN21Qs6TXCsPNRfSfecKXei4xQTURUo&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220627T171231Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYROSXR6FH%2F20220627%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=359fddab2c3ad8369a22838e8bd4b819d099cffac6932efdef6d5a6eebb0a818&hash=25563f91febae99fe6868579684ad4b8b33f9342ef6f6a7179681b0f1e2963d1&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0095895691900077&tid=spdf-9a9e5c62-0047-4856-acdb-4865f9d0bc8c&sid=66a9958d613e2047b5180c15f37a5d760ab4gxrqb&type=client&ua=4d5655080d0206575507&rr=721fced67e9693c7) where I have a doubt in the proof of Lemma 1. It starts by saying that there are at least $|A|/r$ edges of each color, but such a condition is not given anywhere in the statement. How is the partition done? This is not proper edge coloring either.

[image: Lemma I'm referring to]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea is that, for every vertex $x$ in $B$, there is at least one colour $i$ such that $x$ is adjacent to at least $|A|/r$ vertices of colour $i$ (if $x$ is adjacent to fewer than $|A|/r$ vertices of each of the $r$ colours then it adjacent to fewer than $|A|$ vertices in total, which is a contradiction). Then put $x$ in $B_i$. If there is more than one colour such that $x$ is adjacent to at least $|A|/r$ vertices of that colour, just choose one of them. Then every $x \in B$ is in precisely one of the $B_i$, so you have a partition. Note that some of the $B_i$ may be empty.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For each vertex in $B$, find the color which appears most frequently on the edges ending at that vertex. For each $i$, let $B_i$ be the set of vertices in $B$ whose most frequent color is color $i$. Then for each each $x\in B_i$, there are $|A|$ edges coming out, and $r$ colors, so the most frequent color must appear at least $|A|/r$ times.